# sed command a expects \ followed by text

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to add a property in a config file, directly under the comment describing the property. Here is my test file:

```
  # Filename of SSL Certificate

  # Filename of SSL RSA Private Key

  # Filename of SSL Certificate Chain
  ## ssl_certificate_chain=
```

I want to add `ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert` directly under the first comment. My first naive approach was to just replace the comment. However, that doesn't work as the text in the third comment also gets changed, up to the "Chain" text.

So I'm stuck on what sed option to use. I have tried the `a` command in a couple of ways, but I'm fairly new to do this and the volume of similar questions around this `a` command are sending me down a wrong path I think. Here are my attempts. any help is appreciated. Any simlar question to this thats been answered, please point it out. I've been looking for a while today.

**Using `,` as delimter due to slashes in substitute value**

1. `"a,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,"`

Result:

```
  # Filename of SSL Certificate
,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,

,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,
  # Filename of SSL RSA Private Key
,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,

,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,
  # Filename of SSL Certificate Chain
,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,
  ## ssl_certificate_chain=
,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,

,# Filename of SSL Certificate,ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert
```

2. `"s,# Filename of SSL Certificate,a ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert,"`

Result:

```
  a ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert

  # Filename of SSL RSA Private Key

  a ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert Chain
  ## ssl_certificate_chain=
```

Comment: You want to modify the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right path. You just need to match the whole line including the line ending (`$`).

```
sed '\,# Filename of SSL Certificate$,a ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert'
```

This will keep your comment and put the SSL-cert path on the line after.

Comment: I'm testing this on my mac and I'm getting `  # Filename of SSL Certificatenssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert` so its adding to the comment but the newline is not taking effect

Comment: I edited my answer so using append instead of capture and substitute, did you see it?

Comment: No, that gives me "sed: 1: "\,# Filename of SSL Cer ...": command a expects \ followed by text"

Comment: I had to escape the comma but I'm using gnu sed, you have bsd sed. Can you try:  `sed '/# Filename of SSL Certificate$/a ssl_certificate=/etc/hue/conf/https.cert'` ?

Comment: Same result. Let me try this in Linux and get back to you

Comment: This worked in Linux. Thanks for your patience. One more thing would be to indent the new line 2 spaces. I'll play around with that